# Can we create TOC only by merging with another PDF, using iText in Java?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, tableofcontents

Can we create table of content s only by merging with another PDF? The examples I went through in your site have hardcoded string values, but I need to add the titles dynamically.

I don't want to merge the PDF; the PDF I am exporting has other pages like cover page, introduction page, images page etc.. I need to list these as titles in table of contents, the name of the titles varies dynamically. Can you please advise on it?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Google pointed me to this doc on IText's page [merging-documents-and-create-table-contents](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents-itext5/merging-documents-and-create-table-contents). See if that helps.

Comment: Hi AWinkle, thanks for the quick update. I did a lot of studying if Itext , but in all the examples for creating a TOC a hardcoded string value is used. then I went through the merging of docs to write a TOC(the example link you have suggested), so before completing my code I just wanted to confirm that the TOC can be created in PDF only through merging of docs or is there any other way? My requirement was that we did the export in RTF initially, where in for TOC a simple line ("update Field") created the TOC for the doc, since we need to do it automatically I went for PDF.

Comment: Hi , can anybody provide a suggestion please. whether we can create TOC without merging documents?